# Alignment of numbers in table with wide columns

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, siunitx

I have a table with numbers which get aligned using the `S` column type from `siunitx`. Some numbers are put into `\multirow` and with the `\tablenum` macro the alignment works perfectly as long as the columns are only as wide as required by the numbers. But when some text is added in the cells which forces the columns to strech the alignment gets lost, see example.

Is this a bug? Or should I just abandon `multirow` altogether? :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=1.2]}
{Energy} & {Efficiency} & {Uncertainty} \\
14.14 & 10.41 & 3.82 \\
22.10 & 4.17 & 3.14 \\
\multirow{2}*{\tablenum{30.97}} & 1.31 & \multirow{2}*{\tablenum{3.08}} \\
& 1.48 &  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\newbox\mybox
\sbox\mybox{\begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=2.2]@{}}1.31\\1.48\end{tabular}}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=1.2]}
{Energy} & {Efficiency} & {Uncertainty} \\
14.14 & 10.41 & 3.82 \\
22.10 & 4.17 & 3.14 \\
% oops 30.97 &{\begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=2.2]@{}}1.31\\1.48\end{tabular}}& 3.08 \\
30.97 &{\usebox{\mybox}}& 3.08 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\tablenum` command relies on begin able to 'bump' into the side of the column, which can only work if the natural width of the column is maintained all the way down. With a longer header you are going to have to add some dummy digit space to help alignment. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.3]S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=5.5]}
{Energy} & {Efficiency} & {Uncertainty} \\
14.14 & 10.41 & 3.82 \\
22.10 & 4.17 & 3.14 \\
\multirow{2}*{\tablenum[table-format=3.3]{30.97}} & 1.31 & \multirow{2}*{\tablenum[table-format=5.5]{3.08}} \\
& 1.48 &  \\
\end{tabular}
```

\end{document}