# Table with wide headers and thin right aligned column text but entered with headers

Tags: tables

I need some help creating a table with the following properties:

1. Wide(er) headings
2. Thin(er) text in columns
3. Column contents should be right aligned
4. Column contents should be centred with the column heading

This is an almost working table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Wide header 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Wide header 1}}\\
1 & a\\
222 & bb\\
33 & cccc\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But the desired output is like this:
[image]

I have seen this ([Alignment of numbers in table with wide columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212737/alignment-of-numbers-in-table-with-wide-columns)) but refers specifically to aligning numbers and not text).

Simpler solutions will be valued. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! An minimal example would be nice to play with,a s there are several solutions: splitting headers into several lines, playing with the intercolumn space, or rotating column heads.

Comment: Added a small (almost working) example as suggested.

Comment: I stumbled upon this problem again, and revisited this question and the answers.  The solutions below are based on a `\hspace{...}` that needs to be "hand customized" for the width of the header text.

It puzzles me both that  this type of alignment is not required by more people!

Do any of the "tabular-in-steroids" packages may help producing a fully-automated solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
r@{\hspace{3.5em}}
r@{\hspace{3.5em}}
}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Wide header 1}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Wide header 1}}\\
1 & a\\
222 & bb\\
33 & cccc\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `tabulary`, `mathtools` for its `\clap`  command, playing with `tabcolsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 

\usepackage{tabulary, booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

{\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5em}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{RR}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\clap{\textbf{Wide header 1}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\clap{\textbf{Wide header 2}}}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
  1 & a\\
  222 & bb\\
  33 & cccc\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}}
\end{document}
```

[image]